# Authorship attribution in research papers

Tags: publications, authorship

This question is egarding an article in a past publication in a journal or conference proceedings with two or more authors.

If subsequently, i.e., in the post publication period any of the authors desires to  mention/record their respective individual contributions or part attributions, how may that be done?

Are there procedures by publishers to record comments by previous authors through any post publication consent form about authorship claims and copyrights?

Or is it better to write a separate new paper maybe including new updated exclusive individual researches?

Comment: I am not sure if I completely understand: you want to add a short notice that clarifie which author did what, or you want to update the paper with new results?

Comment: The former. To add a short notice to clarify which author did what. Updating  btw was mentioned if that would be a work-around.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to include this after already publishing the article? What benefits do you hope to gain?

Comment: To attribute author wise and item wise due credits, that may be  proportional to time of research performed and corresponding importance of the research work.

Comment: Advice: let it go and move forward. Everyone thinks they did more than others did.

Comment: Thanks for the advice , shall take.

Answer (score 4):

No, it doesn't happen in a recognized forum and for a reason. It is a monumentally bad idea to regularly publish author disputes, which would happen inevitably. There are many (many) questions here from writers with disputes over authorship. Allowing them to continue in public post-publication will do no one any good.

The appropriate way to do this is in a "Contributions" section of the paper itself. All authors need to sign off on that. Some fields have traditions about author order, somehow expressing level of contribution, even if poorly. Other fields assume equal contribution, even if not the same *kind* of contribution in all papers unless otherwise stated in the paper itself.

But any authorship disputes or negotiations should end with the publication of the paper, IMO. Focus on the next intellectual contribution. Work with people you trust. Collaborate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no formal mechanism for doing what you're asking (if I correctly understand you). The only possible grounds under which a journal will agree to add a note to a published work is in the case of an error, or a retraction (for whatever reason). Any further work and contributions should go into a *next* manuscript, where you can properly record the author-wise contributions.